# TrackMouseEvent Problems

Tags: c++, windows, subclassing

I have a subclassed button that I am trying to highlight when the mouse cursor is over it.  However, I cannot seem to get the `TrackMouseEvent()` function to work properly.  Here is the code that creates the subclass:

```
hBtn = CreateWindow(L"button", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, HMENU(400), hInst, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(hBtn[0], subSIproc, 400, 0);
```

Here is the subclass procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK subSIproc(HWND hButton, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uId, DWORD_PTR dwRefData){
     int     HIflag=0;

     switch(iMsg)
      {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
         {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT me{};
            me.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            me.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            me.hwndTrack = hButton;
            me.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            TrackMouseEvent(&me);
            HIflag = 1;
            RedrawWindow(hButton, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
         }
         
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
         {
            HIflag = 2;
            RedrawWindow(hButton, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
         }
         
        case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
         {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT me{};
            me.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            me.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE | TME_CANCEL;
            me.hwndTrack = hButton;
            me.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            TrackMouseEvent(&me);
            HIflag = 3;
            RedrawWindow(hButton, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
         }

        case WM_PAINT:
         {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hButton, &ps);
            if(HIflag==0)  FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(0x007F7F7F));
            if(HIflag==1)  FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(0x00FF0000));
            if(HIflag==2)  FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(0x000000FF));
            if(HIflag==3)  FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, CreateSolidBrush(0x0000FF00));
            EndPaint(hButton, &ps);
         }
      }
     return DefSubclassProc(hButton, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
```

The variable "HIflag" has four possible values, to determine which messages are being received, and when---'0' (gray) for no messages yet received; '1' (blue) for `WM_MOUSEMOVE` received; '2' (red) for `WM_MOUSEHOVER` received; and '3' for `WM_MOUSELEAVE` received.

Here is what is happening:  When I initially run the program, the button is gray (no mouse messages received).  The button remains gray, until I move the cursor onto the button.  At that point, it turns green (indicating "WM_MOUSELEAVE").  It should turn red (for "WM_MOUSEHOVER") and not turn green until I move the cursor away from the button.  The button now remains green, no matter where I move the cursor.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `case` blocks are missing `break`s, so when `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is received then the code will fall through to the code for `WM_MOUSEHOVER`, which will then fall through to the code for `WM_MOUSELEAVE`, which will then fall through to the code for `WM_PAINT`, etc.  So `HIflag` will always be 3 when any fall through to `WM_PAINT` occurs.

You are also leaking the `HBRUSH` that `CreateSolidBrush()` returns.  You need to `DeleteObject()` the brush when you are done using it.

But most importantly, `HIflag` is a *local* variable inside of `subSIproc()`, so it will always be 0 when `WM_PAINT` is issued by the OS itself, rather than when it is reached as the result of fall through.

You need to store `HIflag` outside of `subSIproc()` on a per-button basis, such as inside the `HWND` itself using `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr(GWL_USERDATA)`, `(Get|Set)Prop()`, etc.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
hBtn = CreateWindow(L"button", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, HMENU(400), hInst, NULL);
SetProp(hBtn, TEXT("HIflag"), (HANDLE)0);
SetWindowSubclass(hBtn, subSIproc, 400, 0);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK subSIproc(HWND hButton, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uId, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (iMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
        {
            RemoveProp(hButton, TEXT("HIflag"));
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT me{};
            me.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            me.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            me.hwndTrack = hButton;
            me.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            TrackMouseEvent(&me);
            SetProp(hButton, TEXT("HIflag"), (HANDLE)1);
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
         
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        {
            SetProp(hButton, TEXT("HIflag"), (HANDLE)2);
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
         
        case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        {
            // tracking is cancelled automatically when this message is generated!
            SetProp(hButton, TEXT("HIflag"), (HANDLE)3);
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hButton, &ps);

            COLORREF color;
            switch ( (int) GetProp(hButton, TEXT("HIflag")) ) {
                case 1:  color = RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF); break;
                case 2:  color = RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00); break;
                case 3:  color = RGB(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00); break;
                default: color = RGB(0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F); break;
            }

            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);

            EndPaint(hButton, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hButton, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

With that said, another way to color an owner-drawn button's background is to have the *parent* window handle the [`WM_CTLCOLORBTN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorbtn) message, or at least the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message.  This way, the *parent* window can store the button's `HWND` and its associated `HIFlag` together in an array somewhere, and not have to track the flag inside the `HWND` itself.

For example:

```cpp
Buttons[index].hWnd = CreateWindow(L"button", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, HMENU(index+1), hInst, NULL);
Buttons[index].HIflag = 0;
SetWindowSubclass(hBtn, subSIproc, index+1, 0);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK ParentWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uiMsg)
    {
        case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
        {
            HWND hBtn = (HWND) lParam;

            for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfButtons; ++index)
            {
                if (Buttons[index].hWnd == hBtn)
                {
                    COLORREF color;
                    switch ( Buttons[index].HIflag ) {
                        case 1:  color = RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF); break;
                        case 2:  color = RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00); break;
                        case 3:  color = RGB(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00); break;
                        default: color = RGB(0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F); break;
                    }
                    return CreateSolidBrush(color);
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        // or:

        case WM_DRAWITEM:
        {
            DRAWITEMSTRUCT *dis = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT*) lParam;

            COLORREF color;
            switch ( Buttons[dis->CtlID-1].HIflag ) {
                case 1:  color = RGB(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF); break;
                case 2:  color = RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00); break;
                case 3:  color = RGB(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00); break;
                default: color = RGB(0x7F, 0x7F, 0x7F); break;
            }

            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(color);
            FillRect(dis->hDC, &(dis->rcItem), hBrush);
            DeleteObject(hBrush);

            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK subSIproc(HWND hButton, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uId, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uiMsg)
    {
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT me{};
            me.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            me.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            me.hwndTrack = hButton;
            me.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
            TrackMouseEvent(&me);
            Buttons[uId-1].HIflag = 1;
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
         
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        {
            Buttons[uId-1].HIflag = 2;
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
         
        case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        {
            // tracking is cancelled automatically when this message is generated!
            Buttons[uId-1].HIflag = 3;
            InvalidateRect(hButton, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hButton, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy.  My brain just isn't working today.  I knew that it had to be something obvious---like forgetting the "break" statements.  As for the local variable, "HIflag", I fixed that problem by making HIflag a static variable.  Now, everything works as it should.

Comment: "*I fixed that [local variable] problem by making HIflag a static variable*" - That won't work if you have multiple buttons, as they will all be sharing a single variable. You would need a separate variable for each button

Comment: Thanks.  I will keep that in mind.  Right now, I'm just trying to get the basic functionality in subclassing.  My next problem involves how to highlight the button has been selected.